# Drag Drop jqueryui issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to drag a list and drop it over placeholder.

As soon as text touches a placeholder it should change the background color so as to indicate that the content can be dropped here.

But I am facing issue when there are two droppable placeholder adjacent to each other then when I hover over both and drop it, then it is dropped over both. It should restrict to first one only. Please open below link for reference just drag a larger name and place it over {1}{2} then it should drop on one only.

Is it possible?

**CSS**

```
.textarea {
  background: #00ff00;
  width: 100%
}

.dragitems {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropitems {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dragitems ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 650px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="content">

      <div class="dragitems">
        <h3>
                <span>Available Fields</span></h3>
        <ul id="allfields" runat="server">
          <li id="node1">Name</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node2">Address</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node3">Phone</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node4">Sender Name</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node5">Sender Address</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node6">Sender Phone</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node7">Sender Email</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node8">Other1</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node9">Other2</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node10">Other3</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node11">Other4</li>
          <li class="ui-draggable" id="node12">Other5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="dropitems">
        <div id="TextArea1" cols="50" name="S1" rows="20"><span id="{1}">{1}</span><span id="{2}">{2}</span> thanks and regards<span id="{3}">{3}</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $("#allfields li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "copy",
    revert: "invalid"

  });
  initDroppable($("#TextArea1 span"));

  function initDroppable($elements) {
    $elements.droppable({
      tolerance: "touch",
      hoverClass: "textarea",
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var tempid = ui.draggable.text();
        var dropText;
        dropText = " {" + tempid + "} ";

        var div = document.getElementById("TextArea1");
        var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");


        $this[0].textContent = dropText;

      },
      tolerence: 'intersect'
    });
  }
});
```

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywz1vm8t/)

Comment: I am seeing it working exactly as you say you desire it to work... am I misunderstanding?

http://gph.is/2taW72C

Comment: You **need** to post a [mcve] **in your question**. That's not optional.

Comment: Since you're new to StackOverflow, I have updated your post to reflect what we expect a question to look like. Please review my changes, and the comments posted above so that you understand how to post questions that will not be closed. Lastly, I answered your question. Vote it up, mark it as the accepted solution, and give me a slow clap as you sit at your desk...

Comment: @Aman, Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that you're seeing is by design (i.e., it's not a bug).

The only way to get the functionality that you want is to change your tolerance from `touch` to `pointer`. When you do that, the placeholder will only be highlighted based on the position of the cursor, not the position of the element that you're dragging.

```
$(function() {
  $("#allfields li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "copy",
    revert: "invalid"

  });
  initDroppable($("#TextArea1 span"));

  function initDroppable($elements) {
    $elements.droppable({
      tolerance: "pointer", // Property that was changed
      hoverClass: "textarea",
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var tempid = ui.draggable.text();
        var dropText;
        dropText = " {" + tempid + "} ";

        var div = document.getElementById("TextArea1");
        var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");


        $this[0].textContent = dropText;

      },
      tolerence: 'intersect'
    });
  }
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywz1vm8t/1/).